# instantiate/prefab when it requares a gameobject from the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

Im kinda new.

So when i instaniate a prefab that needs a connection to a object in a scene. EXAMPLE: you have a enemy that is the prefab that requires a transform from the player
i just dont know how. :)

Im looking for a overall solution.

in the  "assets" folder u cannot connect the  prefabs script fields  whit objects that are in the scene.

i have tried nothing, i just cant figure it out so i made a post myself

```
is there a solution as a code for this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to do that. Egzample solution:

```
Transform playerTransform;

void Start(){
    FindPlayerReference();
}

FindPlayerReference(){
    playerTransform = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
}
```

You also can use

```
GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
```

or make a static instance of player.